# Implement a service that should not be stopped by android

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm developing an app that runs as a background service. I need to achieve these:
1. Start the service once the phone is booted using Broadcast Receiver
2. Service should not be stopped by android, it should be running continuously.

I have achieved the first step. For the second step i tried using startForeground() method. This method provides a notification to the user that a foreground service is running. But, i don't want the user to be notified about the service and the service should not be stopped. How can i achieve this? Is there any way to do without using startForeground() method?

will be a great help if an example code is provided to achieve this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

set the `<intent-filter android:priority="integer" >` 
if we set the priority high then the service will be continuously running and catch the events

Comment: This should be set in Service or Receiver? And from the [link]http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element.html i don't think that i can achieve my goal. If yes, can u please explain in detail with the help of the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The Android system will attempt to keep the process hosting a service around as long as the service has been started or has clients bound to it. When running low on memory and needing to kill existing processes, the priority of a process hosting the service will be the higher of the following possibilities:

If the service is currently executing code in its onCreate(), onStartCommand(), or onDestroy() methods, then the hosting process will be a foreground process to ensure this code can execute without being killed.
If the service has been started, then its hosting process is considered to be less important than any processes that are currently visible to the user on-screen, but more important than any process not visible. Because only a few processes are generally visible to the user, this means that the service should not be killed except in extreme low memory conditions.
If there are clients bound to the service, then the service's hosting process is never less important than the most important client. That is, if one of its clients is visible to the user, then the service itself is considered to be visible.
A started service can use the startForeground(int, Notification) API to put the service in a foreground state, where the system considers it to be something the user is actively aware of and thus not a candidate for killing when low on memory. (It is still theoretically possible for the service to be killed under extreme memory pressure from the current foreground application, but in practice this should not be a concern.)
Note this means that most of the time your service is running, it may be killed by the system if it is under heavy memory pressure. If this happens, the system will later try to restart the service. An important consequence of this is that if you implement onStartCommand() to schedule work to be done asynchronously or in another thread, then you may want to use START_FLAG_REDELIVERY to have the system re-deliver an Intent for you so that it does not get lost if your service is killed while processing it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot effectively achieve this as your service will **ALWAYS** be vulnerable to the android's process/service killing poilicy.

Unless you are working with a platform level environment, you **CANNOT** achieve this from an app layer. Unless if your service is killed, you then have a procedure that when it is killed, it will be restarted. That is all you can do. However for a full solution, and have it NEVER be stopped, you cannot do this as this malicious behavior as user apps have no right to be running forever on a phone and be treated specially compared to other applications, especially those that are **WAY** more important like the android System apps and their services.

If you're **NOT** working on the platform level, **DON'T EVEN TRY** to achieve this as you cannot succeed in and making it *completely invulnerable*.

The best you can do is try to keep it alive as long as possible, however if memory is running low and you having been idle for too long, then **EXPECT** to be killed.